# Как правильно ставить ударение: танцОвщица или танцовщИца?

Tags: фонетика

-

Comment: В поэзии, да и в прозе нередко, ударение *плавает*. Ничего страшного или неправильного в этом нет.  
**Испанская танцовщица**  
Умолкает птица.  
Наступает вечер.  
Раскрывает веер   
испанская танцовщИца.  
Звучат удары  
луны из бубна,   
и глухо, дробно   
вторят гитары.   
И черный туфель   
на гладь паркета   
ступает; это   
как ветер в профиль. 
 
<1993> 
Бродский Иосиф

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно танц**о**вщица [не танцовщИца].

Answer (score 0):

танцОвщица. Запомнить можно рифмуя со словами, в которых ударение доподлинно известно. Например, "Муж у танцОвщицы - столЯр, у дрессировщицы - маляр. У столярА жена - танцОвщица,
у маляра же - дрессировщица. В блоге "[Культура речи](http://govorprav.livejournal.com/)" можно посмотреть разные способы запоминания ударений.

Comment: А как насчет культуры рекламы? Третий раз даёте ссылку на непонятно какой блог.

Answer (score 0):

Розенбаум, конечно, прекрасный певец. Однако пустил в народ неверную танцовщИцу. А надо бы танцОвщицу.
Впрочем, и Антонов со своим "грушОвым" не без греха...

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, информация из словаря Резниченко: правильно танцОвщик, танцОвщица: "Вот то-то детки: Им бал, а батюшка таскайся на поклон; ТанцОвщики ужасно стали редки" (Грибоедов).

КОММЕНТАРИИ

Отметим, что норма ударения в этом слове менялась, еще недавно словари рекомендовали танцевщИк (обратим внимание на суффикс ЕВ).

Также у Гумилева: "Но к чему победы в час вечерний, Если тени упадают ниц, Если, словно золото на черни, Видны ноги стройных танцовщИц".

Comment: Словарь нашла, пока в Интернете.

Кстати, когда смотрю в книжном новые орфографические словари, ищу слова типа "риэлт...р", "фитнес (сс)", секвест(р)ировать и т.п.
И пока не нахожу такого, где были бы они были. И не нахожу. 

У Резниченко тоже не нашла "риэлт...р".

Comment: Риелтор (ИЭ), секвестрировать (Е) у Резниченко есть в орфоэпическом словаре.